# Is it possible to automate testing for iOS and webdroid app with Appium on windows?

Tags: appium, mobile-automation

We're about to start a project where we need to automate tests for a webdroid and iOS app. I read that Appium is very recommended for this tasks, but we are quite uneasy on the iOS part. Do we need to use a MAC to actually create the tests for the iOS app or is it possible to write them in windows and then export them to the iOS device to run them?

> Extra information:
> We both have iOS phones where we run manual testing (mostly
> front-end and functional, no backend testing so far)

Comment: you can run test from windows but the device farm should be in a mac for ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every testing company encounters this restriction while starting with mobile automation.

Unfortunately, we require a Mac machine to automate an iOS app.
iOS automation is dependent on Mac because *creating and executing the iOS scripts require dependencies that are only provided by the Xcode.*

Instead of a physical Mac machine, we can also opt for a virtual MAC(VM) to automate and execute the iOS Tests.

Additionally, a platform "TestProject" (Paid Tool) is also available that can help automating the iOS app on the windows machine. It is built on top of popular frameworks like Selenium and Appium. *[Never got the chance to explore it but saw its references on different websites when I was researching about iOS automation]*

Answer (score 2):

> Do we need to use a MAC to actually create the tests for the iOS app or is it possible to write them in windows and then export them to the iOS device to run them?

You will need a Mac running Appium [server] and you can connect to it like a Selenium Grid Node (via Desired Capabilities). This Mac could be a Mac mini in your office or hosted on a third party cloud service (see Cloud Providers tab of [Appium Desktop](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop#the-appium-desktop-inspector) for examples).